# How to show Google Map API only after it has completely loaded?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use the [Places search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) functionality of Google Maps API.

My problem is, the search box shifts and the height of the API container changes after the map is completely loaded.

I've made a [demonstration](http://output.jsbin.com/muyedo) of the problem. Try refreshing the page and you'll observe the above mentioned behaviour.

I found similar questions and the suggestions were --

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
   google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});
```

or

```
window.onload = map_initialize;
```

However, neither of them seem to solve this shift behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to set the `input` to `display:none`, add it to the map on the idle event, then display it.

```
function initAutocomplete() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
        lat: -33.8688,
        lng: 151.2195
    },
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);    
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
    input.style.display = "block";
  });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ugguspwd/1/embedded/result/)

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
// feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
// pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

function initAutocomplete() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -33.8688,
      lng: 151.2195
    },
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
    input.style.display = "block";
  });

  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  var markers = [];
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    places.forEach(function(place) {
      var icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: icon,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      }));

      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initAutocomplete);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
.controls {
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 32px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 300px;
}
#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}
.pac-container {
  font-family: Roboto;
}
#type-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}
#type-selector label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
#target {
  width: 345px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box" style="display:none">
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Your solution works fine, but there is a major problem with it. Try zooming in and out of the map and you'll see the search box *moon walking* to the right and eventually out of the page. :P

Comment: I had a doubt though. What's the difference between the scripts -- `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places` and `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete` ? Which one should I use?

Comment: That is outside the scope of this question.  They both load the same API, see [the documentation for what the &callback= does.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#sync)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `defer attribute` for your `<script>` tag where you loading the `google maps JS api`, and a callback function to initialize your map.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Google map demo</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html,
    body,
    #map_canvas {
      width: 100%;
      height: 700px;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    .infowindow * {
      font-size: 90%;
      margin: 0
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initialize" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    alert("map api loaded");
    // initialize map 
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 2,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.422104808, -122.0838851)
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. However, your solution partially answers the question and misses one of the key aspects of the problem -- the search box!